# Domain of $h(x,y)=\frac{1-xy}{1+x^2y^2}+\ln \left(\frac{1-xy}{1+x^2y^2}\right)$

Tags: multivariable-calculus, continuity

I am asked the following question:

> Let $g$ be the function given by $g(t)=t+\ln t$
>   and $f$ the two variable function given by $\displaystyle f(x,y)=\frac{1-xy}{1+x^2y^2}$. What is the expression of $h(x,y)=g(f(x,y))$? Where is $h$ continuous?

This question has no solution on the textbook, so I would like to check my answer on this forum.

**Answer**

By evaluating the composite function I get

$$h(x,y)=\frac{1-xy}{1+x^2y^2}+\ln \left(\frac{1-xy}{1+x^2y^2}\right)$$

In order to stipulate it's domain, we should have

\begin{align*}
1+x^2y^2 &\neq 0 \quad \text{(always)}\\
\\
\frac{1-xy}{1+x^2y^2} &> 0
\end{align*}

So what we need to consider is every $x$ and $y$ where $xy < 1$

Is that correct?

Comment: Correct!$\mbox{}$

Comment: I have changed the formatting of the title so as to
[make it take up less vertical space](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9686/290189) --
this is a policy to ensure that the scarce space on the main
page is distributed evenly over the questions.
See [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9730)
for more information. Please take this into consideration for future
questions. Thanks in advance.